# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error message at the console for line:

```
var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
```

at following script:

```
$(function(){
    $(".search").keyup(function() { 
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
        if(searchid!=\'\') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "classes/search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;    
    });
});
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: Do you mean `'\search\' + searchid;`?

Comment: `\'search=\'` <- what's that?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe you have an invalid or unexpected token. BTW, many problems in composing strings like this can be avoided by using template strings: `\`search=${searchid}`\`.

Comment: @zerkms, it should be a param search = searchid to be used to make a AJAX call to PHP . This is the complete script:

Comment: Why do you have slash before every quote character? What is it there for?

Comment: people! why you downvote him instead of helping to get things done?

Comment: @Deadalus  1) I never downvote anyones answer, especially someones answer (because we are not in war (: ), 2) who are You to judge me? (;

Comment: @num8er 0) It will only alert me if you spell my name right.  1) It is perfectly fine to downvote wrong answers, and they should be downvoted.  (Yashua's answer is not wrong). 2) I'm judging you based on your prejudgement of others, as evidenced by your question of why people downvoted this question.

Comment: @Daedalus, man (: I'm the first one who upvoted his answer (http://joxi.ru/Y2L88MFnBGZo26). Hehe "prejudgement of others",  I don't care what You think, I said my thoughts, cuz mvasco had wrote question and got 2 downvotes, so it pushed me to write "why his question was downvoted".

Comment: @num8er If you didn't care what I thought, you wouldn't have asked me in the first place.  You judged others, assuming that those that were downvoting, were not helping.  Don't dish it out it you can't take it back.

Comment: funny people... go have some sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to escape quotes in this situation:

```
var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
```

And as commented the next line also has issue. Remove the slashes.

Comment: Thank you, but your proposal doesn't change the error message

Comment: @mvasco That would be because you repeat that same error later in the script.

Answer (score -1):

I think when user types text You want to do request to somewhere.

So in this case even: `var dataString = 'search='+searchid;`  will not help, because it needs to be urlencoded (what if there is some character, for example: `&` that breaks the param list?)

so I recommend to do following, let jquery handle all stuff:

```
$(function(){
  $(".search").keyup(function() {
    // post or get
    $.post(
      '/url/to/search', 
      {search: $(this).val()}, 
      function(response) {
        //here You handle response
      });
  });
});
```

Here is fix:

```
$(function() {

  $('input.search').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
      return; // if search query is empty don't proceed down
    }

    $.post(
      'classes/search.php', 
      {search: $(this).val()}, 
      function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response).show();
      });
  });

});
```

Comment: I have included the complete script, may it help you

Comment: @mvasco I've updated the code in my answer again. It had syntax error.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer from Yashua was first, I guess

Comment: @mvasco I agree, he answered to Your question, but mine has right and concrete code for.